# How to make an actor accept different subsets of messages at different times?

Tags: akka

In some distributed protocols, servers (actors) transition between different roles at different times, and accept different subset of messages depending on the role.

Ideally, an actor should always hold a reference to another actor typed in such a way that it is impossible for it to send the wrong type of message (i.e., a message that the other cannot accept because it is in the wrong role).

The inherent problem is that, like I said, an actor can change role over time, and so the subset of messages it accepts; thus, all other actors holding a reference to it would actually start to hold a wrongly typed reference.

Specifically, I am thinking to Raft consensus algorithm, where (for example) a server in follower state would not accept an `AppendEntriesResponse` message, but it is going to be able to accept it as soon as it transitions to leader state. If the behaviors are parametrized with a `Raft` type that comprises all messages (including `AppendEntriesResponse`), then it is easy to wrongfully send an `AppendEntries` to a follower.

Does Akka have a pattern for this?

Does this pattern also apply to actors running in clusters? Does it apply to both types of communication (ask, tell)?

I know that it is possible for an actor to explicitly ignore some messages, but I believe it can become a bit cumbersome and perhaps prone to errors. Moreover, it does not eliminate the issue that I described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no out of the box pattern that matches exactly this. In fact, I'd strongly consider this an antipattern. Essentially you are suggesting keeping the entire cluster in a strongly consistent state regarding the state of a single actor.

Consider a large cluster of nodes. Akka uses a similar protocol to what you suggest for maintaining the list of cluster members. That protocol can take several seconds (or sometimes even longer) to converge on a new membership list. For cluster membership, that's no big deal because no traffic will be sent to a new member until that consensus is reached. (And a node can quiesce while it is waiting to be officially removed from membership.) For cluster membership, there's effectively no cost to operating under the outdated state, and the consequences of inconsistency in the membership list is high.

But, in your example, let's run through some of the challenges if Receiver A wants to change state. What does it do with messages that it already has in its queue intended for its old state? What does it do with messages it receives between it announces its state change and when consensus is reached? Conversely what does Sender B do when it receives first notification that a state change is being made but before consensus is reached? Does it just pause? Or does feel free to send messages for the new state? What if it hasn't received its replies from messages sent to the old state? Also, how does Receiver A know about all of the actors holding a reference to it? How does it know that someone else might not add a reference through discovery or some other method?

Not to mention that your pattern trades availability for consistency. What happens when consensus can't be reached (perhaps because some nodes and/or clients are behind a network partition or have crashed)? Does the receiver state in its old undesired state? Does it process no messages at all in an undetermined state? Preserve messages in a stash until the state is resolved? (Which would exacerbate the problem of potentially having messages received from clients expecting the old state.)

My point is that there would be a huge amount of overhead in what you are suggesting. And that even if you were willing to accept that overhead, you realistically are going to have process "incorrect" messages anyway. Not unless you are willing to accept huge delays and potential unavailability waiting for each part of the system to completely pause and acknowledge the change. (And even then it seems like you'd want to process the "incorrect" messages if only to log and debug them.) And if you are going to have to handle "incorrect" messages anyway, and wait to drain old messages, you might as well switch the new, desired state and just reply to the "incorrect messages" in some fashion.

Overall, this pattern is typically handled in Akka with just a Behavior change (or a state machine change in classic Akka). And with the new Behavior just returning some sort of "InvalidState" message to the sender (or dropping the message completely, depending on your needs). I've implemented this pattern many times.  Fundamentally, Akka is an asynchronous protocol and that means dealing with unexpected messages is really the responsibility of every actor, even in a typed Akka world.

If that pattern is not enough and you need to be more proactive, you could:

- Allow message senders to "register for state changes". There's some challenges with this because you would want to ensure the list of clients is purged of stale registrants, but the concept is simple. I'm not terribly fond of this pattern, tracking clients feels like an antipattern. But at least it's effectively eventually consistent: you may get some "invalid state" messages from senders that haven't received your state change message, but these are the same messages that would have been in flight already and therefore unavoidable anyway.
- Publish your state in some other method, like distributed data. Fundamentally this is very similar to a world where a senders send a "preflight check" message to check the receiver's current state before sending the actual payload (which I'd normally consider an antipattern), except that by using distributed data you are ensuring that that "preflight check" message is processed locally so there are some potential advantages where state changes are frequent and the normal messages might be slow to respond to. It also gives you a lot of flexibility regarding how long to wait for acknowledgements/consensus before changing state. Although, irregardless, you still have consider state messages that might be inflight.